# The double interpretation of 'a priori' in Kant's metaphysics

Tags: kant

I'm sorry if this question has been asked before.

My question regards the apparent double nature of the term 'a priori' in Kant's Critique of pure reason. Namely, as a *presupposition* for experience and also as *independent* of experience.

On one hand, in the Transcendental aesthetics, Kant consideres space and time as pure - a priori - intuitions, i.e. they're *presupposed* for the possibility of experience in general. In other words, experience *as a whole* would not be possible without them (space and time).

On the other hand, Kant uses the expression to describe a certain type of judgments, particularly, *Synthetic a priori* judgments. These judgments are characterised as *independent* of experience. The best examples of this kind of judgments are the ones we found in Euclidean geometry, which are not modifiable by experience, and hence not up to empirical verification, but they're not derivative of concepts either.

Is the difference between this two considerations of the same term a legitimate interpretation? I ask because with the advent of non Euclidean geometries and the Theory of relativity, we know that the Synthetic a priori judgments present in classical (Newtonian) mechanics and Euclidean geometries work *only* in those frames of references. The status of space and time as a priori *intuitions* however would still remain valid in *any* geometry or physical model. Would that be a correct assessment in your view? I can't seem to find any contradiction between those two statements. What do you think?

Many thanks!

Comment: If something is a presupposition of experience then it is independent of it, so you distinction is not very clear. But it sounds like Kant's distinction between constitutive (presupposition) and regulative (imposition) use of *a priori*, see [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-judgment/supplement4.html). However, to Kant space and time are themselves synthetic *a priori*, and his framework can not accomodate non-Euclidean geometries, it was relativized by subsequent neo-Kantians for this purpose. E.g. Minkowsky geometry is constitutive of special relativity, but is revised in general

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I guess i could reformulate my question as follows: can we satisfactorily maintain the status of space and time as pure intuitions, even for non Euclidean geometries or for nonclassical physics?

Comment: No, our intuitive apparatus is very restricted. We do not have non-Euclidean 3D intuitions (at least not Minkowskian ones), or even Euclidean 4D ones, relativity of time is also highly unintuitive. We can only keep them as constitutive, as is done in SR, QM and QFT. In GR and quantum gravity projects they are discarded even as such. To keep geometric intuition in play we have to map some projections of theoretical manifolds analytically onto 2D or 3D models that we can intuit, but that is far from "pure".

Comment: A priority is defined as "necessary and universal", which fits both characterisations. Mind, a priori means 'from the start', which means that you can presuppose it as a given independently from arbitrary events and experience exactly because it is as necessary and universal a given in any case. Space and time are justified as forms of **human sensory experience**, nothing more, nothing less. And humans have to experience from within a non-relative perspective (i.e. for a person, relativity cannot be immediately experienced, only "from without" via instruments and deductions).

Comment: So, one could say that space and time are sort of the indispensable building blocks of all possible experience, while the a priori judgements present in Euclidean geometry maintain their status as long as we consider them 'from within'?

Comment: The problem arises, for me, when we consider the geometry used in Relativity. It's as if we're saying 'Yes, we have a pure intuition of space and that's Euclidean. But now, thanks to Relativity, we can deduce how real space must be like, and that's completely empirical'.

Comment: But then, the only way in which we can considerer space as an a priori intuition is merely as a precondition for experience in general. All attributes of space - formalized by synthetic a priori judgements - are, in principle at least, subject to empirical evaluation, hence not really a priori.

Comment: A typical misunderstanding of a priori and transcendental philosophy in general is that it was disparate from ordinary experience. To the contrary, it is only valid insofar it is based in it; the 'critical' is about sowing out all metaphysics that are not. It is correct that the physical understanding of space may very well be completely different from the spatial structure in which we perceive, because pure intuitions are the form of *appearance*. Sellars is more clear about Kant being a philosopher of what he calls the manifest image as opposed to the scientific one.

Comment: According to Sellars, science allows for descriptions ever closer to the noumenal reality that is the basis of our phenomenal reality. This historical development of the scientific (and manifest) image was not conceivable in Kant's times.

Comment: But surely, there must be some component of scientific enquiry that is a priori. At the very least, space and time as pure forms of intuition. The advantage of this consideration is that it can contain any geometrical or physical model of nature, without supposing a Transcendental realism.

Comment: The problem here still is the different uses of a priori. It seems like what you describe as a priori is basically "how reality is", i.e. what Kant calls the noumenal. For Kant, his a priori is insofar of importance for all scientific enquiry as the Moral Law (as a law valid for *all* practice) and the a priori of understanding and sensibility of course shape scientific inquiry. For example, whatever geometrical or physical model of nature may be correct or possible, as long as it cannot be *represented* in Euclidean space (e.g. via mathematical formulae in 2D), it cannot be *understood*.

Comment: I meant that 'how reality is' is ultimately unfathomable, precisely because of a priori contents of human perception, that limit our understanding in the realm of phenomena only. I believe that this statement is valid for any kind of geometry, physical theory, etc. and so, we're no closer to the noumenon in Relativity or in Quantum mechanics or whichever model of nature the human mind conceives. A scientific theory may explain or predict certain natural events better than other, but always in the realm of phenomena.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking What you're doing is reinterpreting Kant. Kant quite literally is concerned, in the Transcendental Aesthetic, not with some subjective space of geometry of perception or of the "manifest image", but with physical geometry. This is very clear from the derivations in the *Metaphysical Foundations of Natural Science* that Kant assumes Euclidean geometry (of course, he doesn't even have a word for it, because he lived before the invention of non-Euclidean geometries). Kant is not an anti-realist, in other words, he's a realist. Sure, you can defend Kant by saying that he's... [1/2]

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking ...concerned with the geometry (and chronometry) of ordinary experience and not scientific experience, but you cannot make much sense this way of anything that is said in the *Analytic of Principles* of the first *Critique* and in the *Metaphysical Foundations of Natural Science*. What's more consistent with the spirit of Kant's transcendental enterprise is saying that our understanding of space and time can play its role as conditions of all possible experience regardless of whether they're ultimately acquired empirically or not. This is what neo-Kantians like Cohen etc. did.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking One further note: For Kant, of course, the paradigmatic "variant" of experience is experiment in physics, not ordinary experience (which can just be seen as an imperfect approximation of scientific experience). [From other responses I see that you're a very competent reader of Kant, I just think I know more about this area of his philosophy, so I wanted to correct you on that; I'm open for discussion though]

Comment: @abracadabra Cheers for your input. I am not sure how much we really are in disagreement there. I think when one assumes, like I do, that reality (*Wirklichkeit*) for Kant is strictly restricted to appearance and that which makes it possible and that there are reasons to assume that empirical reality, for him, needs some sensual intuition of the object, the term *realist* has to be clarified by *realist regarding what exactly*. Would you not agree that, given that, scientific and ordinary experience were not any different in these regards in his times but later very much became so?

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking In this context the proper contrast to "realist" would perhaps be "phenomenalist reductionist" who thinks that the base, pre-conceptual, structure of our perceptual space determines the basic form of perceptual judgement (asserting the presence of sense data around some point in this space) to which all of our more complex knowledge reduces to. That's not Kant's position - I'd say his transcendental framework is exactly so significant because it allows us to avoid such a position while accomodating the greatest insights of empiricism, disregarded by realists, i.e. [1/3]

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking ..that for empirical content to be determinate there must be a prior space of possibilities which is tightened with each sensory stimulation (perhaps that's a Spinozian insight aswell... omnis determinatio est negatio?). I agree that in modern times we're observing a divergence between manifest and scientific images. But Kant's way of speaking suggests that he's concerned with experience as involving (see the definition of experience which opens the chapter on the *Analogies of Experience*) experiment, measurement and explanation. His discussion also maps quite well... [2/3]

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking ...onto modern philosophy of physics. For example, Kant discusses successivity and simultaneity as involving respectively order-dependence and order-independence of perceptions, i.e. measurements (second and third Analogy respectively). This has great relevance to quantum mechanics where certain measurements cannot be performed simultaneously and this is reflected in non-commutativity of measurement operators. This is not something I am interested in as an ordinary man but only as a scientist. [3/3] (what I mean by "realists" in my first reply is: metaphysical realists)

Comment: @abracadabra Very refreshing discourse! I can hardly agree with your first comment but think this may be based on a misunderstanding reading the other ones: Since Kant basically tries to make out how we can think reality (at all) and the...structures, if you like, this thinking has to have, would it not be surprising if modern science completely transcended it? That is not my point, though. If you make Kant a metaphysical realist, why his nuanced account of noumena in the practical philosophy? Again: realist about what? Maybe the *existence* of things-in-themselves, yes, what else?

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking When I spoke about realism=metaphysical realism, I meant this fragment: "That's not Kant's position - I'd say his transcendental framework is exactly so significant because it allows us to avoid such a position while accomodating the greatest insights of empiricism, disregarded by realists...". So I'm not attributing metaphysical realism to Kant, this is a misunderstanding.

Comment: @abracadabra I see, thank you for clarifying. I referred to your "Kant is not an anti-realist, in other words, he's a realist." - I always understood his philosophy as saying the world (sum of all experiences = representations) and that which makes them possible is real, which includes very few metaphysical claims like the existence of (an) object(s) causing us to form representations *of something*, while not even including certainty about whether one or many but literally anything. Also, everything he is claiming only applying to these representations as they are the starting point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152263/discussion-between-abracadabra-and-philip-klocking).